# Python parsing a list of strings through another list and return matches

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I have two text files that I have turned into lists. List1 has lines that look like this:

```
'U|blah|USAA032812134||blah|blah|25|USAA032812134|blah|A||4||blah|2019-05-28 12:54:59|blah|123456||blah'
```

list2 has lines that look like this:

```
['smuspid\n', 'USAA032367605\n', 'USAA032367776\n', 'USAA044754265\n', 'USAA044754267\n']
```

I want to return every line in list1 that has a match in list2. I've tried using regex for this:

```
found = []
check = re.compile('|'.join(list2))
for elem in list1:
    if check.match(elem):
        found.append(elem)
```

but my code above is returning an empty list. Any suggestions?

Comment: you want `match` or exact equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do that without a regular expression:

#### Method 1

```
list1 = ['U|blah|USAA032812134||blah|blah|25|USAA032812134|blah|A||4||blah|2019-05-28 12:54:59|blah|123456||blah']

list2 = ['|USAA032812134', '|USAA0328121304', '|USAA032999812134']

found = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j in i:
            found.append(j)

print(found)
```

#### Output 1

```
['|USAA032812134']
```

---

#### Method 2 using List Comprehension

```
list1 = ['U|blah|USAA032812134||blah|blah|25|USAA032812134|blah|A||4||blah|2019-05-28 12:54:59|blah|123456||blah']
list2 = ['|USAA032812134', '|USAA0328121304', '|USAA032999812134', 'blah']

print([j for i in list1 for j in list2 if j in i])
```

#### Output 2

```
['|USAA032812134', 'blah']
```

---

#### Method 3: `strip()` for new lines

You can simply `strip()` and `append()` to your `found` list:

```
list1 = ['U|blah|USAA032812134||blah|blah|25|USAA032812134|blah|A||4||blah|2019-05-28 12:54:59|blah|123456||blah']
list2 = ['smuspid\n', 'USAA032812134\n', 'USAA032367605\n', 'USAA032367776\n',
         'USAA044754265\n', 'USAA044754267\n']

found = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j.strip() in i:
            found.append(j.strip())

print(found)
```

#### Output 3

```
['USAA032812134']
```

Comment: Sorry, list2 has a different format than what I previously thought, I edited the question to show what the elements look like. Does that change your code because this method still returned an empty list when I tried it.